# Applying HTML code inside a PHP code - Syntax Error

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

Good morning,

I'm having a syntax problem error when I try to execute this code:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $output .= '
        <tr>
            <td>'.$row["reqname"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["month"]."/".$row["day"]."/".$row["year"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["empname"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["position"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["account"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["platform"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["processor"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["ram"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["monitor"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["phone"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["phonetype"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["headset"].'</td>
            <?php'. if ($row['status']) : .'?>
            <td>'.$row["status"].'</td>
            <?php else : ?>
            <td>
                <form method="post" action="update-request-status.php">
                    <input type="hidden" name="reqnumber" value="<?php echo $row_message['reqnumber']; ?>" />
                    <button class="button" type="submit" name="completed" value=""><span>New Request!</span></button>
                </form>
            </td>
            <td><a href="records.php?reqnumber='.$row['reqnumber'] .'"><i class="fa fa-edit" style="color: black; font-size: 25px;"></i></a></td>
            <td><a href="delete.php?reqnumber='.$row['reqnumber'] .'"><i class="fa fa-trash" style="color: red; font-size: 25px;"></i></a></td>
        </tr>
    ';
}
echo $output;
```

I think I'm having a problem specifically with the:

```
<?php'. if ($row['status']) : .'?>
                <td>'.$row["status"].'</td>
                <?php else : ?>
                <td>
                    <form method="post" action="update-request-status.php">
                        <input type="hidden" name="reqnumber" value="<?php echo $row_message['reqnumber']; ?>" />
                        <button class="button" type="submit" name="completed" value=""><span>New Request!</span></button>
                    </form>
                </td>
```

As you can see, I tried adding `'.` and `.'` to mimic the other codes but for some reason I'm still getting the error.

PS: Sorry if my codes aren't clean, I tried cleaning it before pasting on here  but for some reason it won't follow the format.

Edit:

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row_message['reqname']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_message['month']."/".$row_message['day']."/".$row_message['year']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_message['empname']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_message['position']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_message['account']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_message['platform']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_message['processor']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_message['ram']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_message['monitor']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_message['phone']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_message['phonetype']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_message['headset']; ?></td>
    <?php if ($row_message['status']) : ?>
    <td><?php echo $row_message['status']; ?></td>
    <?php else : ?>
    <td>
        <form method="post" action="update-request-status.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="reqnumber" value="<?php echo $row_message['reqnumber']; ?>" />
            <button class="button" type="submit" name="completed" value=""><span>New Request!</span></button>
        </form>
    </td>
    <?php endif ; ?>
    <td><a href="records.php?reqnumber=<?php echo $row_message['reqnumber']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-edit" style="color: black; font-size: 25px;"></i></a></td>
    <td><a href="delete.php?reqnumber=<?php echo $row_message['reqnumber']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-trash" style="color: red; font-size: 25px;"></i></a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Could be wrong but I think you're just missing an 'endif' after the termination of your else statement logic.

Comment: Hmm actually I just migrated the code, it was working back then so I think it's more of a Syntax Error :)

Comment: Do you really want to put PHP tags inside the string??

Comment: @RiggsFolly I mean if it's possible with the right syntax then yes :) I'm new to PHP and still learning

Comment: The `<?php` tag only works if the code is on the server. PHP will not run in the browser

Comment: @RiggsFolly Hmm not sure if there are any other alternatives I could do. Please see the original code I just pasted.

Comment: The original code makes sense. Whats wrong with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print HTML with echo, but you can't print PHP because this is interpreted  by Browser

You code should be

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $output .= '<tr>
                <td>'.$row["reqname"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["month"]."/".$row["day"]."/".$row["year"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["empname"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["position"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["account"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["platform"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["processor"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["ram"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["monitor"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["phone"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["phonetype"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["headset"].'</td>';
    if ($row['status']) :
        $output .= '<td>'.$row["status"].'</td> ';
    else:
        $output .= '
                <td>
                    <form method="post" action="update-request-status.php">
                        <input type="hidden" name="reqnumber" value="'.$row_message['reqnumber'].'" />
                        <button class="button" type="submit" name="completed" value=""><span>New Request!</span></button>
                    </form>
                </td>
                <td><a href="records.php?reqnumber='.$row['reqnumber'] .'"><i class="fa fa-edit" style="color: black; font-size: 25px;"></i></a></td>
                <td><a href="delete.php?reqnumber='.$row['reqnumber'] .'"><i class="fa fa-trash" style="color: red; font-size: 25px;"></i></a></td>
            </tr>
        ';
     endif;
}  
echo $output;
```

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

You have an unclosed php tag in your output and you're missing the `endif`

That's what code should be:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $output .= '
        <tr>
            <td>'.$row["reqname"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["month"]."/".$row["day"]."/".$row["year"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["empname"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["position"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["account"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["platform"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["processor"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["ram"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["monitor"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["phone"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["phonetype"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["headset"].'</td>';

    if ($row['status']) :
        $output .= '
            <td>'.$row["status"].'</td>';
    else : 
        $output .= '
            <td>
                <form method="post" action="update-request-status.php">
                    <input type="hidden" name="reqnumber" value="' . $row_message['reqnumber'] . '" />
                    <button class="button" type="submit" name="completed" value=""><span>New Request!</span></button>
                </form>
            </td>
            <td><a href="records.php?reqnumber='.$row['reqnumber'] .'"><i class="fa fa-edit" style="color: black; font-size: 25px;"></i></a></td>
            <td><a href="delete.php?reqnumber='.$row['reqnumber'] .'"><i class="fa fa-trash" style="color: red; font-size: 25px;"></i></a></td>
        </tr>';
    endif;
}

echo $output;
```

But you should look [the Heredoc syntax](http://php.net/manual/fr/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), with this syntax your code would be:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $output .= <<<HTML
        <tr>
            <td>{$row['reqname']}</td>
            <td>{$row['month']}/{$row['day']}/{$row['year']}</td>
            <td>{$row['empname']}</td>
            <td>{$row['position']}</td>
            <td>{$row['account']}</td>
            <td>{$row['platform']}</td>
            <td>{$row['processor']}</td>
            <td>{$row['ram']}</td>
            <td>{$row['monitor']}</td>
            <td>{$row['phone']}</td>
            <td>{$row['phonetype']}</td>
            <td>{$row['headset']}</td>
HTML;

    if ($row['status']) {
        $output .= '
            <td>' . $row['status'] . '</td>';
    } else {
        $output .= <<<HTML
            <td>
                <form method="post" action="update-request-status.php">
                    <input type="hidden" name="reqnumber" value="{$row_message['reqnumber']}" />
                    <button class="button" type="submit" name="completed" value=""><span>New Request!</span></button>
                </form>
            </td>
            <td><a href="records.php?reqnumber={$row['reqnumber']}"><i class="fa fa-edit" style="color: black; font-size: 25px;"></i></a></td>
            <td><a href="delete.php?reqnumber={$row['reqnumber']}"><i class="fa fa-trash" style="color: red; font-size: 25px;"></i></a></td>
        </tr>
HTML;
    }
}

echo $output;
```

More readable, limits risks of mistake, ...